# How to speed up query against index of linked document

Tags: orientdb

I have follow database structure:

```
create class User
create class Social

create property Social.vk string
create property User.social LINK Social

create index User.social unique
create index Social.vk notunique
```

Query `select from User where social.vk = '123'` uses index.

Explain in studio gives me info:

```
 involvedIndexes
 ["User.social","Social.vk"]

 elapsed
 2771.4197
```

It significantly slower than

`select from Social where vk = '123'` which runs at 10-30 millis.

How can i speed up slow query or maybe redesign my data with bidirectional linking?

**upd**
Comparing to query time without index, seems like index not uses, but according 'explain' it uses.

**upd2**
Problem appears when 'vk' field is not unique and has many repeated values

Comment: How about using edges instead of links?

Comment: @IvanMainetti Thanks for response. When i change `=` to `LIKE` query runs at milliseconds `select from User where social.vk LIKE '123'`, so i continue investigation and post results later...

Comment: @IvanMainetti about 'LIKE' - it seems like a bug, because it not working. About links - i 'm not sure, that it simple for me - migrate document database to graph.

Comment: yeah it sounds like bug to me too. You could open an issue on official github. https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues

Comment: Hi @zella I'm trying your case with a set of 300000 Users and I'm getting a very good result: `select from User where social.vk = '123'` elapsed: 0.315418. Which version are you using? I'm on 2.2.12

Comment: @IvanMainetti I found how i reproduced this. See "upd2" section. You can try create notunique index on 'vk' field and fill this field with same value on all records. `select from User where social.vk = '123' LIMIT 1` will be slow. `select from Social where vk = '123' LIMIT 1` will be fast.

Comment: ok but which is your real use case? do you actually need a notunique index?

Comment: @IvanMainetti Perhaps, my application's architecure not ideal, so i need this query ;). It's a bug with sql executor (i reported it). Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6875) with osql. Simple workaround - query indexes directly. So there is no problem with performance.